# Не работает переименование одинаковых файлов

Tags: php

Была написана функция, которая бы переименовывала одинаковый файл в папке, если он уже существует. Однако, если в папке имеется файл с таким названием, то не создается его дубликат по типу - file_1.jpg, file_2.jpg итд

Дебагом путь оказывается верным, но название файла остается прежним и не создается копия

В чем может быть проблема?

```
        $f_path = "/img/cats/";
        $preview = basename($_FILES["preview"]["name"]);
        $previewFile = $f_path . $preview;
        
        $previewNew = pathinfo($preview, PATHINFO_FILENAME);
        $extension =  pathinfo($preview, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
        $counter = 0;
        while (file_exists($previewFile)) {
            $counter++;
            $previewFile = $f_path . $previewNew . "_" . $counter . "." . $extension;
        }

        move_uploaded_file($_FILES["preview"]["tmp_name"], $previewFile);
```

Comment: вы уверены что надо копировать именно в `/img/cats`, с учетом того что это абсолютный путь в файловой системе начиная от корня. Может быть вам надо перемещать куда-то в `_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "/img/cats"` ?

Comment: @teran да, там находятся все изображения. С document_root пробовал - ничего не меняется, так же заменяется существующий файл, заместо создания копии

Comment: точно там? не в каком-нибудь `/www/site.ru/public_html/img/cats` а вот прямо в `/img` ?

Comment: @teran да, он же заменяет файл и var_dump проверял - путь верный

Comment: Вот вывод var_dump: https://ibb.co/4R8LHKb
Что с document_root, что без него - результат один

Comment: @Jean-Claude нет, скрипт находится в другой папке

Comment: создай константу, в нее положи путь от корня диска к корню скрипта https://www.php.net/manual/ru/language.constants.magic.php, все пути формируй от корня диска с помощью этой константы

Comment: @Jean-Claude не создает копию. Просто перезаливает файл в папке

Comment: Все пути верные. Такое ощущение, что игнорируется код с циклом

Comment: для копирования файла нужна другая функция https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.copy.php функция move_uploaded_file() перемещает файл из временной папки в указанное место, вопросы надо излагать понятнее. Ща накалякаю.

Comment: Проблему решил
Был какой-то конфликт переменных, хотя в других скриптах все работает
В цикле переименовал с $previewFile на $previewCopyFile

Comment: @Jean-Claude у меня с отправки формы POST файл поступает. Я на его основе хотел сделать проверку, что если файл уже есть в папке, то каждый раз +1
Но спасибо)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Скорее всего запутался в переменных, давай им осмысленные названия, чтобы за пол секунды по одному только названию было понятно что конкретно находится в переменной.

Такой код работает:

```
//константа с путем к корню скрипта
const ROOT_DIR = __DIR__;

if (isset($_FILES['file'])) {

    $filename = basename($_FILES["file"]["name"]);
    $filename_with_path = ROOT_DIR . '/' . $filename;

    $name = pathinfo($filename, PATHINFO_FILENAME);
    $extension = pathinfo($filename, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);

    $counter = 0;
    while (file_exists($filename_with_path)) {
        $counter++;
        $filename_with_path = ROOT_DIR . '/' . $name . "_" . $counter . "." . $extension;
    }

    move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"], $filename_with_path);

}
```